# Can icosahedral group have subgroup of order 30?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The textbook (Artin) wants me to show that there is no subgroup of order 30 in the icosahedral group. I tried to use the index(2) of the subgroup of order 30, but I can't get any new ideas. What other theorems or ideas can I use?

Another approach:
since the index is 2, we can divide the whole icosahedral group into two cosets, namely H and aH (a must not be an element of H). Then since aH is normal, we now get the normal subgroup of order 30 in the icosahedral group;which is a contradiction by the class equation. Is this right?

Comment: Could you expand on the "contradiction by the class equation" part?

Comment: in my class we take it for granted that the icosahedral group's class equation is 60=1+15+20+12+12